# glTexSubImage2D generates GL_INVALID_ENUM when uploading binary array to Compute Shader

Tags: c++, opengl, compute-shader

I'm having a 2 dimensional array structure of boolean values that I'm trying to upload to an OpenGL compute shader. The shader shall then do some operations on the texture, which is there after downloaded and read back to the original structure.

I'm running into problems when uploading the array though, as I get `GL_INVALID_ENUM` in return. This later crashes the execution when I try to run the compute shader.

**Step 1:** I start by creating the shader and defining some parameters for the textures. I'm only in need of one color-channel so I'm using `GL_R8` and `GL_RED`.

```
//Create compute shader
this->compute_shader_ = new Shader(in_path_shader.c_str());

//Texture data
this->texture_target_ = GL_TEXTURE_2D;
this->texture_format_ = GL_R8;  //Only need one color channel since handling booleans, thus not using GL_RGBA8
this->pixel_format_ =   GL_RED; //Only need one color channel since handling booleans, thus not using GL_RGBA;
this->pixel_type_ =     GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE;
```

**Step 2:** I then create two buffers with `glGenTextures` and set both of their specs like this (`in_id` is the id of a single buffer. `side_length_` is 10):

```
glBindTexture(this->texture_target_, in_id);    //Bind
glTexImage2D(                                   //Allocate to graphics memory
    this->texture_target_,  //Target
    0,                      //Mipmaps
    this->texture_format_,  //Internal format
    this->side_length_,     //Width (x)
    this->side_length_,     //Height (y)
    0,                      //Border
    this->pixel_format_,    //Format read
    this->pixel_type_,      //Type of values in read format
    NULL                    //source
);

glTexParameteri(this->texture_target_, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(this->texture_target_, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(this->texture_target_, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameteri(this->texture_target_, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
```

**Step 3:** Next step is turning my 10x10 2D array into a 1D array and upload it to the texture.

```
//Allocate memory
bool* grid_data = new bool[this->side_length_ * this->side_length_];

//Compress grid into a 1D array
for (unsigned int x = 0; x < this->side_length_; x++) {
    for (unsigned int y = 0; y < this->side_length_; y++) {
        grid_data[x * this->side_length_ + y] = this->grid_[x][y].curr_state;
    }
}

//Upload data to shader
glBindTexture(this->texture_target_, in_id);

glTexSubImage2D(
    this->texture_target_,  //Target
    0,                      //mipmap level
    0,                      //x offset
    0,                      //y offset
    this->side_length_,     //width
    this->side_length_,     //height
    this->texture_format_,  //format
    this->pixel_type_,      //type
    grid_data               //data
);

//NOTE: Here an GL_INVALID_ENUM has been generated

//Free memory
delete[] grid_data;
```

**Step 4:** Finally, before dispatching the work-groups I try to bind the two textures, but it then crashes.

```
//Bind source
glBindImageTexture( //<-Breaks here
    0,                      //Always bind to slot 0
    source_buffer,
    0,
    GL_FALSE,
    0,
    GL_READ_ONLY,           //Only read from this texture
    this->texture_format_   //Format
);
//Bind target
glBindImageTexture(
    1,                      //Always bind to slot 1
    target_buffer,
    0,
    GL_FALSE,
    0,
    GL_WRITE_ONLY,          //Only write to this texture
    this->texture_format_   //Format
);
```

**Shader:** The compute shader has this in the top:

```
#version 450
#extension GL_ARB_compute_shader : enable
#extension GL_ARB_shader_image_load_store : enable

layout (r8, binding=0) uniform image2D texture_source0;
layout (r8, binding=1) uniform image2D texture_target0;
```

What really confuses me is that according to the [reference pages](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glTexSubImage2D.xhtml) `glTexSubImage2D` (used in step 3) only returns `GL_INVALID_ENUM` if the target is not one of the allowed target types. My texture target is `GL_TEXTURE_2D` which should be fine, but the error is still generated.

Comment: What if you change the type of `grid_data` from `bool` to `char`?

Comment: It seems to give me the same result. I tried changing it to ``GLchar`` as well but that didn't help either.

Comment: Debugging OGL is tricky. The error may be triggered by a previous gl-call. Use `glGetError` very often to narrow the culprit search. Also check the parameters at every gl-call have the values you expect, some OOP code may be used wrongly.

Comment: Yeah I have called it through-out the function. There is no error before ``glTexSubImage2D`` and only one afterwards. I have tried checking the variables I pass to ``glTexSubImage2D``, but they look like I expect them to, which makes me believe I've misunderstood how something functions and something that I think is right is actually wrong.